# Delete a row after 1 month or 3 month based on selected validity

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I want to delete old records in my database that stores an entry from an HTML form which consists of

1. ID
2. Name
3. email
4. date_of_entry (timestamp recorded when the user submits form)
5. validity (user can choose either 30days or 90days as validity)

I want to expire the row and delete it after 30/90 days based on the validity period selected from the date_of_entry

I found this, but how do I modify it to suit my need

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE date_of_entry < DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
```

Also please note that i'm using a form which sends the value validity as 30 or 90`$duration = $_POST['duration'];`

And this check should be performed by the MySQL itself. I'm using phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you must delete obsolete rows where current date exceeds `date_of_entry` plus `validity` days in this way:

```
now() > date_add(date_of_entry, interval validity day)
```

> ```
> create table tbl (id int, date_of_entry datetime, validity int);
> ```

> ```
> insert into tbl values
> (1, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -31 DAY), 30),
> (1, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -29 DAY), 30),
> (1, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -92 DAY), 90),
> (1, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -89 DAY), 90);
> ```

> ```
> delete 
> from   tbl
> where  now() > date_add(date_of_entry, interval validity day)
> ```

> ```
> select * from tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date_of_entry       | validity
> -: | :------------------ | -------:
>  1 | 2018-03-11 18:16:43 |       30
>  1 | 2018-01-10 18:16:43 |       90
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=2ca35485b55972ef536e6d888505f003)*

Comment: Could you add comments to make me understand why you are using date_add in delete query

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you would do something like:

```
delete t from mytable t
    where date_of_entry < curdate() - interval validity day;
```

This assumes that `validity` is either the number 30 or 90.

Comment: @McNets . . . I assume you mean "why the downvote".  I too am curious.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE date_of_entry <
  DATE_ADD( CURDATE() ,INTERVAL validity*-1 DAY) ;
```